# Is it possible to click on a link using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I know ti's easy to get href property and request that with urllib32. but the problem is that, my link is not using href. ut's action is handled by javascript. this is the link:

```
<a name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page" title="Next page of results" class="active page_link next" href="#" sid="8" page="2" accesskey="k" id="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page">Next &gt;</a>
```

is there a way to click on it just like we do in browser?

I want to crawl this link and then click on Next link:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Breast%20cancer%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D

Comment: No. If you can extract the link from that, as you said, you can try some URL manipulation. Otherwise, for browser simulation (i.e. clicks, etc), you can use the Mechanize or Selenium libraries.

Comment: No, it's not, JavaScript is interpreted by browser and there is no JavaScript interpreter in Python. You may want to look at tools like Selenium.

Comment: u can use urllib2 module to open the link. Check this one out http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/

Comment: @Gunjan Man please read my question completely, I have no link, the href proprety is #
how to request that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but the approach is different. You will need to understand the get/post request that occurs on clicking that link manually in a browser. That you can do using Network tab of Developer Console of browser. You may also need to maintain session, i.e., receiving, storing and sending cookies. You can use [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for the same.

Comment: and what to request? I have no link to request! the href property is: #

Comment: I am assuming you are using Google Chrome browser, so "what to request" you can find out using the Network tab of Developer Console. Just click on that link manually and see what requests are performed there. Also, dont forget to keep the "Preserver Log" checked.

Comment: Is it possible to do me a favor and click on the link in my question and tell me what to request? I couldn't find anything good, I need to follow next button

Comment: Its a POST request to url - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed with a lot of *Form-Data* and also uses cookies. It will take some time to write complete code. Please click on Next and check the requests being made. This should help as well - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Comment: Do I have to set cookies to get response?

Comment: Yes, in your case you surely need it. But you can use [Requests Session](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) object which itself takes care of session/cookie management.